# Excel to XML VBA - need to skip empty tags

Tags: xml, excel, xsd, vba

I have an Excel 2016 template workbook with an area for users to fill with data (some copy-pasting going on + formulas involved). The users launch a VBA macro to export this in `XML-data`. The problem I have is that the whole XML export area is not always consistently filled (lots of scattered data) and the exported XML-s end up with empty tags that I'd want to get rid of, however not sure, how to do it.

[image]

The VBA code is as following:

```
Sub XML_export()

XMLName = "C:\XML" & "\" & "Transaction_SERVICE_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmddhhmmss") & ".xml"
ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("Data_Map").Export Url:=XMLName

End Sub
```

and the XSD schema for the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2018 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Transaction">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Item" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Quantity" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="FromWHS" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ToWHS" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

This will still end up giving me emptry `<Transaction/>` tag for each unpopulated row in the Excel sheet. How could I just get 4 populated `Transaction` tags in the XML file? Currently it will still always export 10 `Transaction` tags with 6 of those being unpopulated (based on the example). Is `XSD` the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I ended up solving this puzzle more easily than I anticipated. I don't need to make the data entry range in the Excel worksheet so big. I can make it a single row and it will just automatically enlarge along with new entries.

Unfortunately does not look like the data entry range decreases back once data is deleted, however VBA code might help reducing it back to single row after export is completed.